# Accessing Apache server over the Internet

Tags: apache-httpd, port-forwarding

I'm trying to access my Apache server over the Internet.

When I use my external IP to connect from a different system, my router's welcome page is displayed. How can I access the server?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do what's called a port redirect of port 80 to the internal LAN IP address of the server that's running the Apache server. Be aware that doing this will cut you off from accessing your router's web interface.

The other option is to use an alternative port, perhaps 8080. You'll still need to do a port redirect rule on your router, forwarding 8080 to your Apache server's port 80.

The second method will allow you to keep your router's web interface on port 80, however now when accessing your Apache server from the outside, people will have to include the port (8080) in the URLs.

Comment: should i be doing that on my router?

Comment: @nagesh - without knowing more about your environment it's difficult for me to answer. I would guess yes. Also See the duplicate that jasonwryan posted. It has better details than what I provided!